# glossary of biotechnological engineering

Tags: biotechnology, book-recommendation

Similar to [A good book for history of biology/biotechnology for lay people](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/551/a-good-book-for-history-of-biology-biotechnology-for-lay-people)

but not for lay people.

Can anyone recommend an advanced dictionary of biotechnological engineering concepts in English (contemporary, not historical)?

There doesn't seem to be anything adequate at my research institution nor even country.  I have been looking for PDF's and e-books since they can be previewed more easily than ISBN #'s, but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this glossary of Biotechnology and Genetic Engineering](ftp://ftp.fao.org/docrep/fao/003/X3910E/X3910E00.pdf) off [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biotechnology), what do you think?

Or [The Facts On File
DICTIONARY of
BIOTECHNOLOGY
and
GENETIC
ENGINEERING](http://www.bjcancer.org/_Library/UserFiles/pdf/The%20Facts%20On%20File%20DICTIONARY%20of%20BIOTECHNOLOGY%20and%20GENETIC%20ENGINEERING.pdf)

What concepts are you necessarily hoping to include? I'm hoping someone actually experienced in this field can advise.